# Asp.net Do Sth After Every N Record SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

My table has these columns:

```
dataID   dataName   dataCategory
```

For example I'm adding 25 rows into my table. I need to make run such a query, when every new 5 new records added, let's say I want to send mail to my customers

```
5th (do sth) 
10th ex(do sth) 
15th ex(do sth) 
.....so on
```

How to detect these new 5 records from SQL Server and do something? If you can help me about code block also not only SQL query it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a trigger for that. Start with

```
CREATE TRIGGER doSomethingEveryFiveInserts BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW  
       ...
```

First, you could define a counter in a different table.

So continuing the code, for each row...

- retrieve the counter from BD.
- if its > 4, reset it to 0, save it in BD, and then "do your stuff"
- if its < 5, increment it, save it in BD and do nothing (wait for the next loop)

Comment: Thank you for your help and solution.